# How do I extract text from awk results?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

This command returns the entire line where the word "About" is found.

```
! lynx -source google.com/search?q=india | awk '/About */'
```

This will return something like this...

```
<div id=gbar><nobr><b class=gb1>Search</b> <a class=gb1 href="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&tab=wi">Images</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl">Maps</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8">Play</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://www.youtube.com/results?gl=US&tab=w1">YouTube</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn">News</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm">Gmail</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo">Drive</a> <a class=gb1 style="text-decoration:none" href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh"><u>More</u> &raquo;</a></nobr></div><div id=guser width=100%><nobr><span id=gbn class=gbi></span><span id=gbf class=gbf></span><span id=gbe></span><a href="http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en" class=gb4>Web History</a> | <a  href="/preferences?hl=en" class=gb4>Settings</a> | <a target=_top id=gb_70 href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=http://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dindia" class=gb4>Sign in</a></nobr></div><div class=gbh style=left:0></div><div class=gbh style=right:0></div><font size="-2"><br clear="all"></font><table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top"><a href="/webhp?hl="><img src="/images/branding/searchlogo/1x/googlelogo_desk_heirloom_color_150x55dp.gif" height="55" width="150" border="0"></a></td><td valign="bottom"><nobr><form name="gs" method="GET" action="/search"><input type="text" name="q" maxlength="2048" title="Search" value="india" size="41"><font size="-1">&nbsp;</font><input type="Submit" name="btnG" value="Search"><font size="-1">&nbsp;</font></form></nobr></td><td width="100%" valign="middle"><nobr><font size="-2"><a href="/advanced_search?q=india&amp;hl=">Advanced Search</a><br><a href="/preferences?q=india&amp;hl=">Preferences</a></font></nobr></td></tr></table><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td bgcolor="#3366CC" height="1"><img height="1" width="1" alt=""></td></tr></table><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#D5DDF3"><tr><td><img height="2" width="1" alt=""></td></tr><tr><td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4"><tr><td nowrap><font size="-1"><strong>Web</strong></font></td><td nowrap align="right"><font size="-1">About 10,730,000,000 results (<b>0.34</b> seconds)</font></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td><img height="1" width="1" alt=""></td></tr></table><p><a href="/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiih9Hri9niAhWvuVkKHXWUCLkQFjAAegQIDBAH&amp;usg=AOvVaw2q-I4x7L6MSaWE9ziLkwjR"><b>India</b> - Wikipedia</a><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td class="j"><font size="-1"><b>India</b> (ISO: Bh&#257;rat), also known as the Republic of <b>India</b> (ISO: Bh&#257;rat Ga&#7751;ar&#257;jya), <br>
```

But I want to return only the number of results. for e.g.

Expected result:

> About 7,970,000,000 results

(Or only the number without words like About)

What I am actually looking for is to return the number of commas in the count. For e.g. the above example has 3 commas it means the count is "very high" and if there is no , (less than 1000 results) the count should return "low".

Comment: If you want to parse HTML, use an HTML parser. There are tons of options, just stop using awk or sed or grep on HTML source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-dump` in place of `-source`.  This eliminates the html codes:

```
$ lynx -dump google.com/search?q=india | awk -F, '/About/'
   Web About 7,410,000,000 results (0.33 seconds)
```

To print just the number:

```
$ lynx -dump google.com/search?q=india | awk '/About/{print $3}'
7,410,000,000
```

To print just the number of commas:

```
$ lynx -dump google.com/search?q=india | awk -F, '/About/{print NF-1}'
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` intead of `awk`. The `-o` option will just print the part of the line that matches the regexp, instead of the whole line.

```
lynx -source google.com/search?q=india | grep -o 'About [0-9,]+ results'
```

Comment: I tried. grep part does not return anything. grep (GNU grep) 2.25

Answer (score 1):

This should be quite easy to do for you with an expression similar to:

```
([0-9,]+)
```

and for commas we would just use:

```
(,)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3iz0EN/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the count of commas in the number, you can use:

```
pax> echo 'About 7,970,000,000 results' | awk '/About/{gsub(/[^,]/,"",$0);print length($0)}'
3
```

In more detail:

```
/About/                - select line with "About"
gsub(/[^,]/,"",$0)     - replace all non-commas with nothing in whole line
print length($0)       - print out count of the commas
```

Keep in mind that's only if the output of Lynx is *exactly* what you originally stated (as in my `echo` which, as it turns out, it isn't).

For the *actual* output (lots of HTML), there's likely to be more commas that you expected. In that case, you need to strip out everything up to the `About` and the everything from the next space after that (leaving just the number), then count the commas in just *that* bit.

The following appears to work well with your actual query, with the first two `gsub` commands stripping out everything bar the number itself, and the rest being what I put forward above:

```
awk '/About /{
       gsub(/^.*About /,"",$0);
       gsub(/ .*$/,"",$0);
       gsub(/[^,]/,"",$0);
       print length($0)}'
```

Comment: When I pipe it to lynx command instead of echo (as shown in your example) I get 5 (not 3)

Comment: @shantanuo: then your Lynx output is most likely not what you stated in the question. I've checked and this is indeed the case, so I've edited the answer to suit.